# i can't access member from inheriting BaseHTTPServer in python, why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a http server program in python, my RequestHandler class inherit from BaseHTTPServer, it init a member a, but I can't access it where BaseHTTPServer is first init statement, when I change the init statement order, it will be correct.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import BaseHTTPServer

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)
        self.a = 0
        print 'aaaa'
    def do_GET(self):
        print self.a  # will cause exception
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        self.end_headers()

server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler_class = RequestHandler
httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

when I changed `__init__` order, it correct, why?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import BaseHTTPServer

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        # change init order
        print 'aaaa'
        self.a = 0 
        BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)
    def do_GET(self):
        print self.a  # I got
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        self.end_headers()

server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler_class = RequestHandler
httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the request is handled in `BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__` (to be exact, superclass' `__init__`).

`do_GET` method is called while processing the request; At that time, `self.a = 0` is not executed; cause the `AttributeError`.

---

In short, the `do_GET` method is called before the `self.a` line for the first code.

- `RequestHandler.__init__`

  - `BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(..)`

    - ...
    - `do_GET`
    - ...
  - `self.a = 0`